# Search for files with a specific file extension in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, file-extension

In Windows Explorer, I would like to search for all files in a specific folder and its subfolders with the file extension .doc. To do that, I tried to enter `.doc` in the search bar on the top right of the window. That gave me as a result all the files containing `doc`, not necessarily with that file extension, including folders named "doc".

In Windows XP, there was if I remember correctly something to only search for one file type, but I can't find anything like that in Windows 7.

How to only search for files with a specific file extension and not other files which contain that extension in their name?

Comment: Have unchecked the "Hide extensions for known file types" in Folder Options? Then when you can search for a certain file with a specific extension.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Windows Vista and higher support the Advanced Query Syntax (AQS). To search for files with a particular file extension (.doc), you'd type:

> ext:.doc

or simply:

> *.doc

(the 1st one is better - it's well worth learning AQS)

To find exact matches, enclose the extension in double quotes:

> ext: ".cs"

**AQS References**

[Advanced Query Syntax (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Mastering Windows Search using Advanced Query Syntax | Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/03/mastering-windows-search-using-advanced-query-syntax/)

[Exploring Vista's Advanced Search](https://blog.codinghorror.com/exploring-vistas-advanced-search/)

[How to Search for Files Created Between Two Dates in Windows](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-files-created-between-date-range/)

Comment: still works in Windows 10! ext: ".cs" was perfect for my case