# File Search Multiple File Types Supported

Tags: pdf, search

What is the best way to mass search html, epub, and pdf file's contents?

Windows explorer doesn't really support this properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using Advanced Query Syntax, supported in Windows Vista and higher. To search multiple file types, use this syntax:

```
ext:.bmp OR ext:.htm OR ext:.txt
```

Use as many operators as you'd like.

**AQS References**

[Search for files with a specific file extension in Windows 7 - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1115643/search-for-files-with-a-specific-file-extension-in-windows-7/1115646#1115646)

[Advanced Query Syntax (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Mastering Windows Search using Advanced Query Syntax | Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/03/mastering-windows-search-using-advanced-query-syntax/)

[Exploring Vista's Advanced Search](https://blog.codinghorror.com/exploring-vistas-advanced-search/)

[Become a Windows Search ninja with Advanced Query Syntax | Ed Bott](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/2010/02/become-a-windows-search-ninja-with-advanced-query-syntax/)

[How to Search for Files Created Between Two Dates in Windows](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/search-files-created-between-date-range/)

Comment: This doesn't work for epubs http://superuser.com/questions/561392/index-epubs-windows

Comment: Works fine here.. where .epub isn't even a registered file type in my system. http://imgur.com/a/FjJ8p

Perhaps rebuilding the search index is the solution.

Comment: the contents of the epub not the title

Comment: Although I appreciate you answering I would like to say this doesn't answer the question to my knowledge

Comment: No problem. But the original question din't mention about searching file "contents". Given the question, i did my best.

Comment: I have edited the question I wasn't specific but thought it was implied

Comment: It certainly is not "implied" IMO.